# Error on Swift Package installation(Mapbox-maps-ios

Tags: swift, mapbox

[I am trying to following MapBox IOS SDK for my project through swift package Manager dependency. Facing issue

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvueB.jpg)

I've try to do:

'touch .netrc'
'open .netrc'

'machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password PRIVATE_MAPBOX_API_TOKEN'

but it still does not resolve the problem
the current verion of xCode is 14.2

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure about .netrc file and info.plist MBXAccess token, you can try installation w/cocoapods
pod 'MapboxMaps', '10.11.1'